# Sharing services between Kestrel instances

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel

Is there a mechanism to share the service dependencies registered between 2 Kestrel servers running in a single process?

I'd really want to segregate some backend support endpoints on one port while the main application runs on another.

From what I know `.UseUrls("http://*:80", "http://*:8080")` would expose 2 ports for the same Kestrel instance and HTTP pipeline, which isn't exactly what I want.

Given a structure like this

```
Kestrel on :80
   /api/... - normal api 
   /ping - liveness checks
Kestrel on :8080
   /health - health checks
   /metrics - metrics
```

I know I could have a shared `Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)` method registering the common pieces, but the `IServiceCollection` would produce a completely separate `IServiceProvider`.

I'd like to register services for both servers to consume from the same root `IServiceProvider` but have different HTTP pipleline/endpoint configuration.

Is this possible?

Comment: A fairly basic option would be to set things up "as normal", listening on the two ports, but using `MapWhen` on `IApplicationBuilder` to set up a different pipline for :8080 requests, for example. That might not be the segragation you're looking for, but it's a simple approach.

Comment: @KirkLarkin right but that’s a lot of configuration and I’m not sure if it’s easy to do that with middlewares

Comment: Have you seen the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#branch-the-middleware-pipeline) (scroll down to `MapWhen`)? You end up with two `IApplicationBuilder`s, which are each configured however you need. The example in the docs uses a query-string value to decide which middleware pipeline to use, so it appears you could do something similar but checking the port instead.

Comment: @KirkLarkin that was more-or-less what i needed. please add an answer as an example.